# Most Effective Crop Patterns Using Scarecrows and Sprinklers?

Tags: stardew-valley

Recently, I've been the victim of a high number of crow attacks on my crops.  I'd like to add some scare crows to my crop fields so that the highest number of crops are protected by the scarecrows.

**What is the most effective crop field pattern for using scarecrows with sprinklers?**

Comment: Most effective in what measure?

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer If I had to guess, most effective in that the scarecrow arrangement takes up the least amount of crop space while also covering the largest area?

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer - TimmyJim is correct, I'm looking to maximize the number of crops covered using the least amount of space.

Comment: The effective range of Scarecrows is pretty big, you're far better optimising sprinkler layout instead

Comment: @HazyKingdom What about Sprinkler placement? Is that a concern? Should I just assume an unlimited area for crops?

Comment: I did not take sprinkler placement into consideration, I've edited the question to include sprinkler layout within the pattern.

Comment: I don't think there's a single best pattern for all sizes of fields

Comment: I only needed two scarecrows before i started going full ancient berry kegging.  Worrying about scarecrow efficient is a waste of time imo.  I would recommend setting up kegs and preservers to ramp up your profits.

Comment: Oh so you were full ancient berry kegging in the first season? Would love to hear that strategy! Even rushing the seed maker takes until about early summer at best.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TL;DR: There is no "most efficient" pattern that works across all farm layouts. Build your farm to yield as many farmables as you can, then do your best to cover the area with scarecrows.

---

Unlike sprinklers, scarecrows' effective range is circular (actually more octagonal). This can create some problems when trying to place them since it usually means you either have lopsided, asymmetrical layouts (which bothers people who like aesthetics) or you'll eat up a few farming spaces (which bothers people who aim for efficiency). Add to that the complication of different farm layouts and terrain obstacles, plus sprinklers and beehives, and you've got yourself quite the conundrum. No matter what you end up doing, you'll have to sacrifice either appearances or maximum payout if you want to keep up 100% scarecrow coverage.

A scarecrow's is an 8 block radius, as seen on [the wiki](https://stardewvalleywiki.com/Scarecrow):

[image: Scarecrow range]

Unfortunately, because of the rounded shape of the range, you are forced to stack areas of effect in order to condense the coverage to a rectangular farm. You can try a "staggered" approach (one scarecrow on one side, another scarecrow on the other side but somewhat lower), which has the benefits of maximum space efficiency with minimum overlap:

```
X

       X

X

       X
```

Or you can do a "simplistic" approach (one scarecrow on each side at equal spacing), which is easier to set up but uses up more space and scarecrows.

```
X     X

X     X

X     X
```

The method I have used is to make one large crop field (16x16), putting one scarecrow on the outside of each corner. I also place one scarecrow in the center of the crop field, which covers the missing "hole". Then I'll fill in the sprinklers and crops as best I can.

```
X     X
   X
X     X
```

Overall, because of various terrain obstacles, I don't think there is a 100% fully efficient method. Just try a couple different methods and use what you like best.

Comment: I'd like to point out [this site](https://stardew.info/planner/) that allows you to experiment with a farm layout.  Using this tool, you can play around with various scarecrow setups and see what you like before you build it in game.

Comment: @Ryre did you just re-upload the same image to a different URL? The old image was working fine O_O

Comment: The old image was broken when I visited the url directly; oddly enough, I can see it working now.  I searched imgur for an equivalent image for my edit.